# Responsive webpage: Top navbar to menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm in the progress of learning how to make website with html, css, and js. I've been learning through extreme trial and error and recently found out what responsive webpages were and I absolutely love the concept of it.

Now I've been meddling around with w3-schools templates to see some design patterns. I came across an error that I haven't seemed to have found an answer to.

Let's get to the point. On Chrome when I switch my browser size to mobile, the top navbar is supposed to convert into a menu on the top right and dropdown whatever was located in the top navbar.

Here's some code snippets.

```
<!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
<div class="w3-top">
  <ul class="w3-navbar w3-white w3-card-2" id="myNavbar">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" class="w3-wide">LOGO</a>
    </li>
    <!-- Right-sided navbar links -->
    <li class="w3-right w3-hide-small">
      <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#team"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> TEAM</a>
      <a href="#work"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> WORK</a>
      <a href="#pricing"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i> PRICING</a>
      <a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <!-- Hide right-floated links on small screens and replace them with a menu icon -->
    <li>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w3-right w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium" onclick="w3_open()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars w3-padding-right w3-padding-left"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Sidenav on small screens when clicking the menu icon -->
<nav class="w3-sidenav w3-black w3-card-2 w3-animate-left w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large" style="display:none" id="mySidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" class="w3-large w3-padding-16">Close ×</a>
  <a href="#about" onclick="w3_close()">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#team" onclick="w3_close()">TEAM</a>
  <a href="#work" onclick="w3_close()">WORK</a>
  <a href="#pricing" onclick="w3_close()">PRICING</a>
  <a href="#contact" onclick="w3_close()">CONTACT</a>
</nav>
```

Here's the associated js:

```
<script>
// Modal Image Gallery
function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img01").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal01").style.display = "block";
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
}


// Toggle between showing and hiding the sidenav when clicking the menu icon
var mySidenav = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

function w3_open() {
    if (mySidenav.style.display === 'block') {
        mySidenav.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        mySidenav.style.display = 'block';
    }
}

// Close the sidenav with the close button
function w3_close() {
    mySidenav.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

Here's the error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: w3_open is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM3994:1)**

[W3 Template Code](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_templates_startup)

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT: When added to my index.html it worked, but when added to the index.html with angular routing it doesn't work. Any thoughts?**

Comment: assuming your css is correct, have you added this to the head of your html? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: Yeah it's been added. Not to be mean, just look at the link I posted to the w3 template to see all its content.

Comment: Yes I looked at that but wasn't sure what your head looked like, It will be a media query issue then, you need to show us your css

Comment: If the linked template is the full code of what you're doing, I'm not seeing any issue, it switches to mobile menu and it opens when clicked no errors for me.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess and suggest that **_there may be something else that is breaking your JS code_** (a syntax error somewhere else maybe) that is causing the **ReferenceError**.  Have you omitted some other Javascript code from your snippet, possibly above the definition of `w3_open()`?

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. When do you see that error? Which element do we have to click to trigger the error?

Comment: On Chrome, when I Inspect Element, I click "Toggle Device toolbar" and it changes my viewing mode as some popular mobile devices. When I see the side menu, I click it and get the error listed.

I copied the linked template verbatim and got the error listed.

Comment: Only thing I omitted was the Google maps snippet in the script. Basically what was posted in the question. When I go to the link on my mobile device I see the nav bar, but when I'm testing it on the chrome browser I get the error. Is there anyway I can see how my site looks when it's supposed to be for mobile devices?

Comment: If you **did not** copy the code verbatim, then I'd suggest posting up a jsbin with your code.  It's likely that when you omitted the Google maps snippet _**you may have created a syntax error**_ which would cause the the following code to break _including_ the w3_open function declaration

Comment: It's weird. I tried viewing the template on my mobile device and it works fine. When I try to force the smaller screen on chrome, I get the error. What is that supossed to mean?

Comment: I figured out that it has something to do with my routing using angular.